# What is "register-management" in spring-cloud commons?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, service-discovery

I'm implementing a service-discovery solution following the discovery SPI provided in [spring-cloud-commons abstractions](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/multi/multi__spring_cloud_commons_common_abstractions.html)

For auto-registration, there is a builtin spring configuration property:

```
spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.register-management: false
```

which binds to a configuration class [AutoServiceRegistrationProperties](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/serviceregistry/AutoServiceRegistrationProperties.java#L28).

**I can find no information on this property**, and it seems not implemented by `spring-cloud-eureka-client` or `spring-cloud-consul-client`

Please help me to understand:

1. What behavior is managed by this property?
2. What is meant by "register management" in the context of service-discovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a management port setup (actuators running on a separate port). You can register the management as a separate service that can be discovered.

So if you register a `userservice` and have set `management.server.port=8081` then there will be a service registered (`userservice-management`) whose port is 8081 and the same host has the `userservice` instance.

Comment: Ok thanks - is there a default implementation that I'm overlooking somewhere in spring-cloud library? Or should my code provide an impl by inspecting the value of management.server.port (or some other property to see if actuator is enabled) and then call self.register(<host>:<managementport>) – Adam Hughes 31 mins ago

Comment: it's not implemented by eureka-client, but it is in consul and zookeeper

Comment: Is it implemented in zookeeper .. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/blob/master/spring-cloud-zookeeper-discovery/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/zookeeper/serviceregistry/ZookeeperAutoServiceRegistration.java#L63